# Определение частей речи и удаление ненужных

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nlp, pymorphy2

Мои данные - 1641 постов. В цикле все функции работают, кроме как раз таки исключения ненужных частей речи (functors_pos), которую я пыталась реализовать с помощью MorphAnalyzer. Не могу понять, где ошибка, возможно, в функции pos.

```
# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('all_text1.tsv', delimiter = '\t')
# Cleaning the texts
import re
import nltk
import pymorphy2
from pymorphy2 import MorphAnalyzer

functors_pos = {'CONJ', 'PREP', 'PRCL', 'INTJ', 'NUMR', 'NPRO'}
corpus = []
def pos(word, morth = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()):
    return morth.parse(word)[0].tag.POS

for i in range(0, 1641):
    review = re.sub('[^А-Яа-я']', ' ', dataset['Post'][i])
    review = review.lower()
    review = review.split()
    review = [word for word in review if pos(word) not in functors_pos]
    review = ' '.join(review)
    corpus.append(review)
```

Comment: MorphAnalyzer работает. В чем ваш вопрос?

Comment: Моя дата - 1641 пост. В цикле все функции работают, кроме как раз таки исключения ненужных частей речи (functors_pos), которую я пыталась реализовать с помощью MorphAnalyzer. Не могу понять, где ошибка, возможно, в функции pos.

Comment: Добавьте минимальный набор входных данных, ожидаемое поведение, фактическое поведение.

Answer (score 1):

Пример:

```
import pandas as pd
from pymorphy2 import MorphAnalyzer
from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize, regexp_tokenize

data = [
  "В цикле все функции работают", 
  "Кроме как раз таки исключения ненужных частей речи (functors_pos), которую я пыталась реализовать с помощью MorphAnalyzer.",
  "Не могу понять, где ошибка, возможно, в функции pos."
]    
dataset = pd.DataFrame({"Post":data})

functors_pos = {'CONJ', 'PREP', 'PRCL', 'INTJ', 'NUMR', 'NPRO'}

def clear_text(col):
    pat = r"[^А-Яа-яёЁ']"
    return col.str.replace(pat, " ").str.lower()

def filter_pos(sent, morph=MorphAnalyzer(), excl=functors_pos):        
    return ' '.join(word 
                    for word in word_tokenize(sent) 
                    if morph.parse(word)[0].tag.POS not in excl)

dataset["Post_filt"] = clear_text(dataset["Post"]).map(filter_pos)
```

---

исходный DataFrame:

```
In [36]: pd.set_option("max_colwidth", 150)

In [37]: dataset
Out[37]:
                                                                                                                         Post
0                                                                                                В цикле все функции работают
1  Кроме как раз таки исключения ненужных частей речи (functors_pos), которую я пыталась реализовать с помощью MorphAnalyzer.
2                                                                        Не могу понять, где ошибка, возможно, в функции pos.
```

после обработки:

```
In [38]: dataset["Post_filt"] = clear_text(dataset["Post"]).map(filter_pos)

In [39]: dataset["Post_filt"]
Out[39]:
0                                                  цикле все функции работают
1    раз исключения ненужных частей речи которую пыталась реализовать помощью
2                                              могу понять где ошибка функции
Name: Post_filt, dtype: object
```